# trying to parse parquet file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

As stated above I am trying to parse a parquet file into a pandas data frame but I always get the error from the screenshot below. I also switch from VS Code to Sublime because VS Code did not accept the pyarrow import even though it was there [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGdaZ.png). The line above also gives the same error.

thanks in advance guys

edit: I know tried the following which lead to the following error [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHEIj.png)

Comment: try : 
from pyarrow.parquet import ParquetDataset

dataset = ParquetDataset("file.parquet")
table = dataset.read()
df = table.to_pandas()

Comment: unfortunately this gives me the same error @RIM

Comment: @Bleatingquagga This error means that pyarrow was able to find a file named `IBES_Detail.parquet` but it did not seem to be a parquet file.  Can you verify that it is not a zip file or some other format or perhaps it was partially downloaded and corrupt?

Comment: @Pace I downloaded it as a Zip file and then extracted it

Comment: @bleatingquagga Are you able to open the file with ParquetViewer? (https://github.com/mukunku/ParquetViewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could resolve your problem:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(path=your_file_path)
```